# CSS to make a div active on page load

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a page that renders the variants of a product (color choices). I have all the availability and pricing of each variant hidden (display:none) through the CSS until the variant image is clicked. How can I get the first variant to be active when the page loads? Here is the javascript that handles the selections and the CSS for the variants.

Sorry if this is a newb question, I feel like its something simple I am missing.

Javascript:

```
function selectThumb(el, productid) {
        $('.product-variant-line-thumb,.add-to-cart,.overview .prices,.overview .stock').removeClass('active');
        $('#addtocart_' + productid + '_EnteredQuantity').closest('.add-to-cart').addClass('active');
        $('.price-value-' + productid).closest('.prices').addClass('active');
        $('.price-value-' + productid).closest('.prices').next('.stock').addClass('active');
    };
```

CSS:

```
.product-details-page .product-variant-list, .product-details-page .overview .prices {display:none;}
.product-details-page .product-variant-list, .product-details-page .overview:nth-child(2) .active {display:inherit;}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="overview">
                        <div class="product-name">
                            <h1 itemprop="name">
                                Bag
                            </h1>
                        </div>


<div class="prices" itemprop="offers" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
        <div class="product-price">

            <span itemprop="price" class="price-value-1420">
$39.99            </span>
        </div>
            <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD">
</div>

    <div class="stock">
        <span class="label">Availability: </span><span class="value">In stock</span>
    </div>



<div class="prices" itemprop="offers" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
        <div class="product-price">

            <span itemprop="price" class="price-value-1421">
$39.99            </span>
        </div>
            <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD">
</div>

    <div class="stock">
        <span class="label">Availability: </span><span class="value">Out of stock</span>
    </div>

                                        <!--Back in stock subscription-->

<div class="prices" itemprop="offers" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
        <div class="product-price">

            <span itemprop="price" class="price-value-1532">
$39.99            </span>
        </div>
            <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD">
</div>

    <div class="stock">
        <span class="label">Availability: </span><span class="value">In stock</span>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're setting `.prices` to `display:none;` you could do this:

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.prices:first-child').addClass('active');
});
```

CSS:

```
.prices.active {
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: My CSS is set like that. I was hoping for a CSS solution in case a customer has javascript turned off, but this is likely the best route. Thanks!

Comment: The pure CSS solution would be to just manually add the active class to the first div(which should be fine providing you aren't generating those divs dynamically).

Comment: They are generated from partial views.

Comment: I guess another thing you could do would be to use the `first-child` selector in the CSS. If you always want the first `.prices` div to be active, just do `.prices:first-child { display:block; }` in the CSS.